# Cascading dropdown list does not bind data to the 2nd dropdown

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a main view. Once the posting is done, it will render a partial view in the main view.

My partial view has a cascading dropdown list that changes the 2nd DropdownList items based on the selected value from the 1st DropdownList.

Here is my Dropdown in my Partial View.

```
@model MigratingDB.Models.ViewModel
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DropdownViewModel.SelectedValue1,
    Model.DropdownViewModel.List1, "Select",htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddl1" })
</div>

<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DropdownViewModel.SelectedValue2,
             Model.DropdownViewModel.List2 = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()), "Select",
             htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddl2" })
</div>
```

The script I tried based from [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/cascading-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc).

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#ddl1').change(function () {
            $("#ddl2").empty();
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Getddl2Items", "Controller")',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: selectedValue },
                success: function (value) {
                    $.each(value, function (i, val) {
                        $("#ddl2").append('<option value="' + val.Value + '">' +
                             val.Text + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed' + ex);
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Foo (ViewModel vm)
    {
        // Dropdownlist
        var list1 = // get items frop ddl1
        vm.DropdownViewModel.List1= new SelectList(list1, "Value", "Text");

        return PartialView("_PartialView", vm);
    }
        // Get ddl2 Items
        public JsonResult Getddl2Items (int id)
        {
            var ViewModel = new ViewModel();
            var list2= // get ddl2 items from the database 
            ViewModel.DropdownViewModel.List2= new SelectList(list2, "Value", "Text");
            return Json(ViewModel.DropdownViewModel.List2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Every time I tried to select a value from the ddl1, it errors and show

> Failed [object Object].

What causes this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a long post that I tested and works.  Since it is long, you can pick out the parts you need.  Let's work together to figure out why it is not working for you.

This will be your table and data creation:

```
--Use your database name instead of Breaz
USE [Breaz]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblCity]    Script Date: 7/17/2017 9:46:31 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblCity](
    [Cityid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CityName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [stateid] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblState]    Script Date: 7/17/2017 9:46:31 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblState](
    [stateid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [statename] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [stateid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblCity] ([Cityid], [CityName], [stateid]) VALUES (1, N'Phoenix', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[tblCity] ([Cityid], [CityName], [stateid]) VALUES (2, N'Las Angeles', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[tblState] ([stateid], [statename]) VALUES (1, N'Arizona')
INSERT [dbo].[tblState] ([stateid], [statename]) VALUES (2, N'California')
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblCity]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([stateid])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblState] ([stateid])
GO
```

Create your edmx, by going through visual studio wizard.

Create your view model:

```
//user your namespace
namespace Testy20161006.Models
{
    public class Registration
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter State")]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter City")]
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Your controller/classes:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult getCity(int id)
    {
        //use your dbcontext name from edmx wizard 
        using (BreazEntities33 objEF = new BreazEntities33())
        {
            var ddlCity = objEF.tblCities.Where(x => x.stateid == id).ToList();
            List<SelectListItem> licities = new List<SelectListItem>();

            licities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select State--", Value = "0" });
            if (ddlCity != null)
            {
                foreach (var x in ddlCity)
                {
                    licities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.CityName, Value = x.Cityid.ToString() });
                }
            }
            return Json(new SelectList(licities, "Value", "Text", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IndexStackOverflow(Registration registration)
    {
        //put breakpoint here to see values coming back from view
        return View(registration);
    }

    //use your name of action that starts the process, named in routeconfig.cs
    public ActionResult IndexStackOverflow()
    {
        bindState();
        return View();
    }

    public void bindState()
    {
        //use your dbcontext name from edmx wizard 
        using (BreazEntities33 objEF = new BreazEntities33())
        {
            var state = objEF.tblStates.ToList();
            List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select State--", Value = "0" });

            foreach (var m in state)
            {
                li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = m.statename, Value = m.stateid.ToString() });
                ViewBag.state = li;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is your view:

```
@model Testy20161006.Models.Registration
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>IndexStackOverflow</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#State").change(function () {
                $("#City").empty();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("getcity")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { id: $("#State").val() },
                    success: function (city) {
                        $.each(city, function (i, city) {
                            $("#City").append('<option value="'
                                                       + city.Value + '">'
                                                 + city.Text + '</option>');
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        alert('Failed.' + ex);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State, ViewBag.state as List<SelectListItem>, new { style = "width: 200px;" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.City, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "--Select City--", new { style = "width:200px" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div><input type="button" value="submit" /></div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'll try this at home. Anyway, I tried to use the debugger on my controller action  "Getddl2Items " and it returns the data that I needed. And also, the `Failed [object Object]` stops showing meaning the request succeeded. But somehow, Every time I clicked a value in the 1st Dropdown, and still I got no value in the 2nd Dropdown even though the request is a success.

Comment: Do you have an example that returns Json value from a SelectListItem in a ViewModel?

Comment: @progammer101 I changed my post so the button on the view does not submit.

Comment: @progammer101 added another answer that show return Json value from a SelectListItem in ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that returns Json value from a SelectListItem in a ViewModel.

```
public class ReturnJsonVM
{
    public List<SelectListItem> licities = new List<SelectListItem>();
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //use your name of action that starts the process, named in routeconfig.cs
    public string IndexStackOverflow()
    {
        using (BreazEntities33 objEF = new BreazEntities33())
        {
            var ddlCity = objEF.tblCities.Where(x => x.stateid == 1).ToList();
            List<SelectListItem> licities = new List<SelectListItem>();

            ReturnJsonVM returnJsonVM = new ReturnJsonVM();
            if (ddlCity != null)
            {
                foreach (var x in ddlCity)
                {
                    returnJsonVM.licities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.CityName, Value = x.Cityid.ToString() });
                }
            }
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnJsonVM.licities);
            //put your break point here to see example that return Json value from SelectListItem in ViewModel
            return json;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer by the way. I fixed the problem just by removing the ViewModel and put its properties to the MainViewModel to access directly. Don't know what happened, but sure it works.